# free form wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a voucher to distribute electronically and I would like people to complete a form on my WordPress site and when they click submit, they receive a e-mail with the voucher.

Is there any plugin out there for that? If there is not, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: This might be better to ask over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: u are right, my bad, english is not my first language, thx for u answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the contact form 7 plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/